# Free programs to draw graphs?

Tags: math-software

allow me to draw graphs, lines, curves such as parabolas, set intervals with sliding bars etc.

I have tried geogebra but it is very limited and is a pain to use. For example, you cannot set a line to have a particular gradient, you can only draw a line and then measure the gradient afterward. And to plot parabolas, you cannot plot equations but rather do it in a microsoft paint style.

Comment: You can try sagemath or Wolfram-alpha(to some extent)

Comment: on internet everything is free, so take advantage of the progress.

Comment: try [link](http://desmos.com)

Comment: You can indeed plot parabolas via equations in GeoGebra, just as you can enter the equation of a line to plot it. Just type them in.

Comment: gnuplot with octave is a nice combo. I use it for most of my every day plotting needs.

Comment: @amd Do I need to download geogebra for that? I can't  find that tool on the online version.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. Select the “Algebra” app in the online version of geogebra, and you’ll get a tool that’ll let you type equations in and graph them. You’ll still have all of the interactive geometric tools, too.

Answer (score 1):

[Desmos](http://www.desmos.com/calculator) is an excellent graphing calculator, it's very easy and intuitive to use. It also implements derivatives and, since the last update, integrals too.